# Framework for readable and maintainable acceptance tests

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing

Im looking for an acceptance testing framework with readable syntax (like [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)'s plain text specs) but as an internal domain specific language (DSL). First I was thinking about [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_feature_spec) but non technical customers run screaming away if they see the syntax!

So is there an acceptance testing framework optimized for readability providing an **internal** (ideally typesafe) DSL and running on the JVM?

Comment: Which DSL do you want? Cucumber's stepdefs can be called a DSL

Comment: The emphasis is on 'internal' DSL.

Comment: Why doesn't Cucumber + Capybara in step defs suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a Cucumber-like framework running on the JVM, you can use [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm). In the github page, there are examples for a variety of java and java-based languages such as Groovy and Scala.

I don't really understand what you mean by "internal" dsl. Cucumber-jvm features are plain Given-When-Then user stories in .feature files, why wouldn't they fit your definition?

I've been using it with Java and Junit, it's almost as simple as Cucumber's ruby implementation.

Comment: I've accepted that there is no way to have an internal DSL and business user friendliness. Even the `class` keyword and curly braces are too technical. So indeed, I ended up with cucumber-jvm.